# input=submit is submitting before confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, forms

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="general-btn" value="Submit" name="decision" id="trigger">
```

First JS call:

```
$("#trigger").submit(function (e) {
    userSubmit(e);
});
```

Then I followed [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yvm32bLm/1/) fiddle from [jQuery Deferred and Dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758928/jquery-deferred-and-dialog-box/18474005#18474005)

```
function userSubmit(e){
var question = "Do you want to start a war?";
    confirmation(question).then(function (answer) {
        console.log(answer);
        var ansbool = (String(answer) == "true");
        if(ansbool){
            alert("this is obviously " + ansbool);//TRUE
        } else {
            alert("and then there is " + ansbool);//FALSE
        }
    });
}
```

but the form is submitting before the confirmation is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confirmation is asynchronous, so the submit handler does not block and returns immediately, causing the submit.

You can stop the submit using `e.preventDefault()` and then trigger the submit manually using the `submit` function. However you need to keep a flag that checks whether you already confirmed, so you do not cancel and ask again, or you can remove the submit handler if the submit was confirmed.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the code you used, I usually with a form use the onclick attribute instead for the 'HTMLInputElement.onclick' as the console would say.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: Using inline event listeners is widely considered bad practice.